# Error in retrofit GET request

Tags: android, retrofit

I am using retrofit for api calling in my android app. In one of my request url of request is like this:

```
/v1/employee/1?employeeId=50124
```

my retrofit method is:

```
@GET("/v1/xyz/{employeeId}?companyId={companyId}")
    void getEmployee(@Path("employeeId")int employeeId, @Path("companyId") int companyId, Callback<List<Model>> callback);
```

but when i call api it throws error, please help how to append url like this in retrofit GET request.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For dynamic query parameters use @Query.

Try using the below code:

```
@GET("/v1/xyz/{employeeId}")
void getEmployee(@Path("employeeId")int employeeId, @Query("companyId") 
int  companyId, Callback<List<Model>> callback);
```